# How to check the width and the height before resizing the window?

Tags: jquery

Hello guys I have this function which is scale the container everytime when I resize the window. But first time when I load the page is showing the original size of the container. How can I check the width and height of the window first thing and then to show me the container on the right sizes without resizing the window?

```
$(window).resize(function(evt) {
    var $window = $(window);
    var width = $window.width();
    var height = $window.height();
    var scale;
    // early exit
    if(width >= maxWidth && height >= maxHeight) {
        $('#banner').css({'-webkit-transform': ''});
        $('#ad').css({ width: '', height: '' });
        return;
    } 
    scale = Math.min(width/maxWidth, height/maxHeight);
    $('#banner').css({'-webkit-transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')'});
    $('#ad').css({ width: maxWidth * scale, height: maxHeight * scale });
});
```

Comment: You should use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) instead of Javascript

Comment: Thats the point. I want to use jQuery no CSS

Comment: you can use the same code inside your `resize` and do it on `load`

Comment: Why? CSS is considerably better and more efficient than a Javascript solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the `load` to your function like:

```
$(window).on('resize load', function(evt) {
    var $window = $(window);
    var width = $window.width();
    var height = $window.height();
    var scale;
    // early exit
    if(width >= maxWidth && height >= maxHeight) {
        $('#banner').css({'-webkit-transform': ''});
        $('#ad').css({ width: '', height: '' });
        return;
    } 
    scale = Math.min(width/maxWidth, height/maxHeight);
    $('#banner').css({'-webkit-transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')'});
    $('#ad').css({ width: maxWidth * scale, height: maxHeight * scale });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).on('load resize', yourfunction);
```